# Bracha on food and drinks eaten between dairy/meat/fish?

Tags: shabbat, blessing, meat-and-milk, meal-seudah, shavuos

I do not know the answer to this, even though it comes up every Shabbos.

My usual behavior is not to make a bracha on the glass of juice between fish and meat. I don't know if this is correct.

I *certainly* wouldn't know if it were correct if it were, say, a piece of bread between dairy and meat. (Would one make a blessing on this bread? Which blessing? I assume one would wash. Would one bentch? [Notably, the  standard advice--"eat some bread and wash on everything"--doesn't work.])

---

> Various considerations; please feel free to skip reading them: 
>   1. The idea that we make a new bracha on a l'chaim during the meal. (But it [seems](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6718/does-the-blessing-over-bread-cover-beverages) this is [quite complicated](http://www.berachot.org/halacha/18_devarim.html), and may only apply
>   to wine, and then only in [some](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27204/why-do-ashkenazim-say-a-bracha-for-each-of-the-four-cups/27209#27209) cases, possibly depending on the
>   machshava during kiddush, and on [whether one drank kiddush
>   immediately](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Food_That_Comes_during_a_Meal#Drinks).)
>   2. More generally, the idea that we make a new bracha on anything (i.e., dessert) not considered part of the meal -- although [this](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Food_That_Comes_during_a_Meal)
>   too [seems](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17968/having-dessert-in-mind) [to](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70393/what-to-do-when-uncertain-regarding-a-bracha-on-dessert-during-a-bread-meal?rq=1) be [really complicated](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2683/brochos-on-desserts).
>   3. The idea that we [don't make a bracha on liquids](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2685/1516). 
>   4. The idea that we [make](http://mevakeshlev.blogspot.com/2015/01/bracha-on-broth.html) a bracha [on](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1456819/jewish/Why-No-Special-Blessing-Before-Drinking-Water.htm) some [liquids](http://www.yeshiva.co/ask/?id=450). 
>   5. The idea that the palate-cleanser is tafel to the meal. Even bread as a tafel ([i.e.,](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16096/bread-between-fish-and-meat-requires-hamotzi) with salty fish) doesn't get a bracha. But
>   does that apply here? And what if there's no [single] meal?
>   6. The idea that we might have nutritional, taste or other benefit from the palate-cleanser, even if its primary purpose is to fulfill a
>   halacha. (And even then--I've never heard of not making a bracha on
>   something consumed to fulfill a halacha.)
>   7. Wine/alcohol and bread, in particular, are sometimes deemed "important enough to get a bracha" in various situations. So if one
>   were being used as a palate cleanser, maybe it would get a bracha. 
>   8. In deference to [these](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/6726/1516) authorities, maybe the best course to say shehakol on something else before the meal and drink less than a
>   revi'is total to cleanse the palate. But how much is necessary to
>   cleanse the palate? And what if the palate-cleanser is bread?
>   9. Safek berachos lehakel. But I don't know about safek safeika berachos lehakel, which [seems to apply](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/70433/1516) to brachas on food,drink.
>   (It would seem that in such a case, you could or even should make the
>   bracha. {[Or maybe not.](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Shehakol#When_should_one_make_a_bracha_on_water.3F)}) But is a palate-cleanser "food"? 
>   11. Would having the palate cleanser in mind at the moment of kiddush and/or hamotzi [*definitely* mean](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/17968/having-dessert-in-mind?noredirect=1&lq=1) you wouldn't need a bracha
>   later? And which one should it be -- kiddush or hamotzi? Does it
>   depend on what you will use to clean your palate?
>   12. Would @Cashcow 's suggestion [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70393/1516) work -- to eat a bit of bread with your drink (and/or with your kinuach bread) thereby making
>   it part of the meal? 
>   13. It seems that the Mishnah Berurah rules that palate-cleansers [need a bracha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/17978/1516). (But there is still the question of whether it is
>   covered by Hamotzi/kiddush in the case of palate-cleansers consumed
>   during a meal.)
>   14. Vezot HaBracha (p. 72, chapter 8) rules that on fruit juice one doesn’t make a Bracha during the meal. (Also saw [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/30156/thirsty-from-before-starting-a-bread-meal-now-wanting-to-drink-in-the-middle-of?rq=1) that one doesn't on water, but that doesn't help much.)
>   Sorry if it seems to be a lot of questions in one...I have no idea how to divide it

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/16096

Answer (score 1):

You stated that you are speaking of food items with the same bracha (*shehakol*) and you intended it for the entire buffet, which includes the fish, drink, and meat. As a result, there should be no reason to say another bracha. Also note that [Bread between fish and meat requires hamotzi?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/16096/bread-between-fish-and-meat-requires-hamotzi) explains why one should wash and say hamotzi if eating bread between them. Of course if one washed and said hamotzi before the entire meal, the problem does not exist.

Comment: What about if one is drinking juice between fish and meat in a motzi meal? (Where one has/hasn't made kiddush on wine)

Comment: @SAH Once one has made motzi, then everything in the normal meal is included (except for special dessert rules).

Comment: So my question is then "what's considered part of the normal meal." There are, afaict, dessert rules and also beverage rules, fruit rules, and also perhaps palate-cleanser rules for brachas during the meal. In my no.13 above, I have a Mishnah Berurah that a palate-cleanser does get a bracha... but I'm still not sure about during a meal

Comment: Once you wash for bread and say hamotzi, all foods and drinks in general are covered during the meal. This includes a glass of juice between fish and meat, even on a shabbos or weekday. Grape juice or wine needs a brachah though if there was no kiddush on grape juice or wine before the meal.